# Rest API integration with joomla

Tags: api, rest, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I have to integrate this API (http://api.iqrez.com/documentation/) in a template of joomla 3.0. Do you know if there is an extension that can permit me to integrate this API? Or please can you give me technical infos for integrate it?

Thank you in advance
Luca

Answer (score 0):

1. A [Joomla Template](http://docs.joomla.org/Template) provides a theme or style mechanism for the website.
2. The API you've pointed to is described as "[Online Booking Engine](http://www.iqwareinc.com/products/iqrez/)"
3. The [Joomla Extension Directory (JED)](http://extensions.joomla.org/) has a section on [Bookings & Reservations](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations)
4. [Searching the JED for "iqrez"](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=iqrez) reveals no hits.

None of these are questions suitable for StackOverflow, which is why you're getting downvoted.

To integrate a Joomla site with a 3rd party API you will need to create an extension, the [Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/) website has [a Developer portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers). Depending on the exact functionality you want and the degree of integration you will need to create either a "[component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Components)", "[module](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Modules)" or "[plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Plugins)". Or a combination of all three.